# Find the Expectation of uniform random variables

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics, statistical-inference

I need to find the expectation of the following problem, but now assuming that U is uniformly distributed from a to b i.e U~(a,b). My problem is that I don't understand how to obtain the limits of integration.

[image]

Comment: Answer looks OK. We don't need the joint density of max and min, individual densities are enough, since in general $E(U-V)=E(U)-E(V)$, linearity of expectation, which holds always, we don't need independence.

Comment: @AndréNicolas basically the final anwers for U~(a,b) is going to be the same as this one, but with an extra factor i.e (b-a)(n-1)/(n+1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $U=(b-a)X+a$, where $X$ is uniform on $(0,1)$.

So the max of the $U_i$ is $a$ plus $(b-a)$ times the maximum of the corresponding $X_i$, and the same observation holds for the minimum. So the   difference is $(b-a)$ times the corresponding difference in the $X_i$ world, and the expectation is $(b-a)\frac{n-1}{n+1}$.

Alternately we could compute the mean of the max of the $U_i$, and of the min, without going to the joint distribution. For in general $E(S-T)=E(S)-E(T)$.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!!!! it is exactly what I have! THANK YOU

Comment: You are welcome. It is often useful to express "new" random variables in terms of "known" random variables. Life is particularly pleasant if the new random variable is linear in the old.